# Coded Ui testing. Cann't locate List items in Open File dialog

Tags: coded-ui-tests, listitem

I am testing some Windows Store app with Coded UI.
In my case i should open some files through open file dialog.
I create UI maps for Main page and for Open window. 
[OpenWindowMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yw4QJ.png) and 
[Control was added normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuhRD.png)
It looks normal until my program try to find List item to choose file.

Thats a part of code where i try to find List item control.

```
Gesture.Tap(MainMap.UIAppUnderTest.UIPlusPopupWindow.UIItemMenu.UIOpenfileMenuItem);
OpenWindowMap.OpenWindow.WaitForControlExist();
Gesture.Tap(OpenWindowMap.OpenWindow.TopItemsPane.ChooseFolderPane);
Keyboard.SendKeys(Classes.Core.TestDirPath);
Keyboard.SendKeys("{ENTER}");
Gesture.Tap(OpenWindowMap.OpenWindow.UIItemsViewList.UI0ListItem);
```

In last raw i get an exeption like this:

```
Test method AppUnderTestCUIT.Tests.PlaylistTest1.PlaylistFormatsTest threw exception: 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException:
The playback failed to find the control with the given search
properties. 
Additional Details:  
TechnologyName:  'UIA' 
FrameworkId: 'DirectUI' 
AutomationId:  '0' 
--->
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

Does anybody have an ideas?

Answer (score 0):

can you locate your controls from UIMap editor? does Visual Studio find them? I don't see in your code that you try to find the control. You just wait for it a default amount of time, specified in `Playback` settings, and then proceed further with actions. If the control isn't found on UI, you get the exception from above.

Try finding the control from UIMap editor using `Locate Control` option.

Your search properties contain a very few details about the control. It is probably the issue. Especially your `AutomationID` normally shouldn't be '0'. If it is '0', then ask your development team to provide you with some identical and meaningful `AutomationID`.

cheers,
Alex

Comment: Hi Alex, I create this control with UIMap editor and it contains property 'AutomationID'. Locate control does not work, but when i open UIMap editor and try ti identity control with CTRL+I it shows on map as already created.

Comment: Even in the image you provided the 'AutomationID' property is '0' as well as in the exception text. Why would you  like to use gestures in that 'Open' window? it looks like a standard Windows dialog. If you want to open a file, just type its path and hit open or enter key. No need to mess around with those elements, because I assume that they are not of your testing focus.

Comment: I should locate this element to add Assertions that gives me a chance to  check which formats my app can open. If i use field "Open file" i didn't catch is chosen file opens or not

Comment: @VedmidValery Try to use `FriendlyName` and/or `Name`. You can change that in propertiers of the control in UIMap Editor. Or you can manually create a new UITestControl (for more information refer to [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2009/02/12/hand-coding-a-coded-ui-test.aspx) Alternatively, try using the combobox on your form, which enumerates all file extensions your app allow to load. If this list of extensions is correctly specified, then it will work. Once again, remember, you don't need to test Windows dialogs in depth, cause it's what Microsoft suppose to do.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I was surprised the MS Coded UI could not interact well with MS Windows file browser.

In the end I recorded a mouse click on the "File name:" text box at the bottom of the window. This was one of the few things that did work with Coded UI on this window. I then chose Generate Code, naming it "Common_Filebrowser_Filename".

I then opened the "UIMap.uitest", found my method "Common_Filebrowser_Filename", right clicked and chose "Move Code to UIMap.cs". I don't know if you are familiar with this option. If you don't do this, the code changes you make get overwritten when you record your next test!

Lastly, I wrote the code below, you can see my custom code between comments...

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void FindFile()
    {
        this.UIMap.Common_Filebrowser_Filename();

        //Custom code to find file....

        //Enter Directory
        String directory = "C:\\myDir\\testFiles";
        foreach (char c in directory)
        {
            Keyboard.SendKeys(c.ToString());
        }
        //Enter filename
        String file = "\\myTestFile";
        foreach (char c in file)
        {
            Keyboard.SendKeys(c.ToString());
        }

        //End of custom code to find file
    }
```

Disclaimer: I am using Windows 10 (latest version), VS2017 (latest). I have not yet experimented to find out whether I need to change my test method to include the file extension if I am running where the file browser does shop the file extension. In my case extensions are hidden and I don't know if showing file extensions would confusing my test.

I also freely admit that the 2 backslashes before the file name should probably be at the end of the directory rather than at the start of the file but have not tested this change.

You will have to record your own test to click the Open button at the bottom right of the File Browser window.

I hope this helps.